# Firefox, error when accessing https url

Tags: firefox, ssl, https, hotspot

I'm connected through a public wifi hotspot.
No problem when using IExplorer.
When I use Firefox, I obtain the following error message after asking for any https url, as for example https://www.google.com:

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.google.com.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

How can I solve?

Comment: check your proxy...

Comment: This can occur because of a misconfiguration of AntiMalware software that includes "internet security" or because something in the chain is redirecting the https URL to http, and your browser does not like it.

Comment: So, there is a proxy or AntiMalware that prevents Firefox from working but not IExplorer? Really?

Comment: The problem may not be due to a proxy or antimalware issue, but [Firefox can be configured to use the system proxy settings, which is what Internet Explorer uses, or can be configured to use a manual proxy setting](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/firefox/finding-proxy-setting.php) in which case even though Internet Explorer may not be routing your HTTP/HTTPS connectivity through a proxy, Firefox may be using a proxy. Also, with some antimalware products, you can configure the software for "safe surfing", which might be turned on for one browser, but not another.

Comment: This is probably the hotspot's captive portal interfering with your connection.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be repair with uncheck the TLS encryption. `Tools` > `Option` > `Encryption (tab)` > and `uncheck TLS 1.0`.

---

**Update**.

Look for these preferences([`security.tls.version*`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.*)).

- *security.tls.version.min*
- *security.tls.version.max*

In the Awesomebar, type or paste **`about:config`** and tap the **Go** arrow. 
Type `tls` into the search box and tap the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to find all preferences that contain ***tls***.

According to a comment in the code:

```
// 0 means SSL 3.0, 1 means TLS 1.0, 2 means TLS 1.1, etc.
```

So try setting both **min** and **max** to **2**, to force *TLS 1.1*, and see whether that works.

<sub>[`See Reference`](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/questions/959239#answer-436462)</sub>

Comment: Sorry, tried with no luck. Same error as before.

Comment: @Toc updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry, nothing even after your update. By the way, Firefox 24 does not have Encryption tab on Adavnced section in options window.

Comment: Furthermore, by the way, I have recognized that my IE is set to use TLS 1.0 and not 1.1.